# JavaScript ternary operator: how to assign multiple object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was wondering whether it's possible to assign multiple object properties in one ternary operator statement.

In my example I'm verifying whether the current object of my link-object is of type `page`. If so, two object properties should be assigned the value `undefined`.

The structure of my object is broadly speaking as follows:

```
value: {
   type: string,
   page: {...},
   article: {...},
   external: {...}
}
```

I tried using the following code:

```
value.type === 'page' ? (value.article = undefined, value.external = undefined) : value.page
```

I would however get a typescript error message: *Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.*

I'm confused since I'm, in my opinion, making an assignment. Any suggestions what went wrong?

Comment: Why abuse the conditional operator *even more* - why not not just use a normal `if`? EDIT: this is what the TypeScript error tells you as well - you have a random expression in the middle of the code. It expects something more meaningful.

Comment: In my mind: to make the code more lean and easier to read. Or am I not supposed to use the ternary operator for such an operation?

Comment: _"to make the code more lean and easier to read"_ - How is a one-liner with multiple operators easier to read than an `if ... else ...`? o.O

Comment: No, it makes your code *harder* to read as you are trying to make multiple *mutually exclusive* operations *on the same line*. Reading and understanding the entire line has to be done all at once by whoever will maintain this code. Having separate discrete chunks of logic that you can focus on *without* having to also juggle the rest in your mind leads to lower cognitive load and easier to understand and reason about code.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I was not opinionated about which is the better way. Your argument makes perfect sense, so I will be using `if ... else ...`

Comment: @Andreas there isn't even an `else` for this. It's just `if (condition) { /* do two assignments */}`. Nothing happens when the condition fails. It's simple control flow that has been folded into an expression with an `else` part added that basically serves as a noop just, to satisfy the conditional operator.

Comment: @VLAZ That was a generic `if ... else ...`. Just ignore the `else ...` part :D

Comment: @Andreas yeah, I was just trying to point out how the conditional operator was a poor fit for this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair ternary statements are most/best used with assignments (possibly by design).

You can achieve what you asked for by deconstructing and reconstructing the object as such

```
value = (value.type === 'string')? {...value, article:undefined, external:undefined} : value ;
```

Here we simply override the values of article and external to what we want in this case undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can, by using `[]` like this:

```js
value.type === 'page'
    ? [value.article, value.external] = [undefined, undefined]
    : value.page
```

However, if might be more readable and clear if using `if`.

Comment: This won't change the error. The construct is still an expression.